# Invalid Input Syntax when Uploading CSV to Postgres Table

Tags: postgresql, csv

I'm fairly new to postgres. I am trying to copy over a file from my computer to a postgres server. I first initialize the table with

```
CREATE TABLE coredb (
id text, lng numeric(6,4), lat numeric(6,4),
score1 numeric(5,4), score2 numeric(5,4));
```

And my CSV looks like this:

```
     ID       lng      lat    score1   score2
      1     -72.298  43.218   0.561     0.894
      2     -72.298  43.218   0.472     0.970
      3     -72.285  43.250   0.322     0.959
      4     -72.285  43.250   0.370     0.934
      5     -72.325  43.173   0.099     0.976
      6     -72.325  43.173   0.099     0.985
```

However, when I try to copy the CSV over, I get the following error

```
COPY coredb FROM '/home/usr/Documents/filefordb.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "lng"
CONTEXT:  COPY nhcore, line 1, column lng: "lng"
```

Oddly enough the csv imports just fine when I set the `CREATE TABLE` parameters to text for all the columns. Could someone explain why this is happening? I am using psql 9.4.1

Comment: Are you sure your CSV looks like that? That has no commas in it.  It looks like you'd need to change your `DELIMITER ','` to something better and use the `WITH HEADER true` option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `HEADER true` to tell COPY to skip the header line.